# How do I force a scrollbar in a <select> to go to the top of the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<select multiple='multiple' size='3'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery how do I force the scrollbar in the select to go to the top?

Comment: without actually selecting the item?

Comment: Doesn't actually matter if it gets selected or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("select").scrollTop(0)
```

Should work, and, depending upon your browser, might work.  But I would not count on it.  It does not work in Safari 4, but does work in Firefox 3.5.9